# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`pedido`,

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error when I trying to run the code:

ERROR:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Pedido_Usuario1` FOREIGN KEY (`Usuario_idUsuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`idUsuario`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

This is my code:

```
<?php



include 'conexion.php'; 

$numero = $_POST["numero"]; 
$fechac = $_POST["fechacreacion"]; 
$fechav = $_POST["fechavencimiento"]; 
$con = $_POST["condiciones"]; 
$sub = $_POST["subtotal"]; 
$iva = $_POST["iva"]; 
$total = $_POST["total"]; 
$observaciones = $_POST["observaciones"]; 


$insertar ="INSERT INTO pedido(numero,fechaCreacion,fechaVencimiento,condiciones,subtotal,iva,total,observaciones)VALUES ('$numero','$fechac','$fechav','$con','$sub','$iva','$total','$observaciones')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

if(!$resultado){
   echo mysqli_error($conexion);
}
else {
   echo 'Se ha llenado el formulario con exito';
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: I have recently red some stuff about database design and Foreign keys & primary keys and stuff :s but I'm afraid its too much for me to help you with. My best geuss is there is another table connected to pedido which needs to be inserted... ;( hopefully I can learn something here too.. waiting for other comments

Answer (score 0):

can you add `show create table pedido`?
i think that there is a column Usuario_id that you are implicitly inserting null into.